# Spring Loaded não está funcionando

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

Tenho um projeto Spring 3.1.4

e estou configurando o `spring-loaded` segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tomcat executa certinho mas o `spring-loaded` não está funcionando qualquer alteração tenho que levantar o tomcat novamente.

Answer (score 2):

A [documentação](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded#running-with-reloading) é clara ao dizer que classes carregadas a partir de arquivos JAR não são recarregadas, somente arquivos `.class` individuais que estão no disco, em algum diretório incluído no `classpath`.

Sem conhecer o seu ambiente em detalhes não posso afirmar isto de forma conclusiva, mas suponho que:

- Você está incluindo seu projeto como um jar em `WEB-INF/lib` portanto ele não será recarregado; ou
- O local onde suas classes estão sendo compiladas pelo Eclipse não está no `classpath` do Tomcat, logo elas não são encontradas.

Sobre o segundo item, veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654237/1683070) (em Inglês) que menciona como um usuário resolveu o mesmo problema, acessando a opção ***Launch configuration*** no Eclipse, aba ***classpath***, adicionando o projeto em ***user entries***.